# Variable Scope in VS C# vs VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with 2 projects - 1 VB, 1 C#. I want to see and edit a global variable of my VB project from my C# project. I have declared the string variable (in VB) as Public Shared.

I can't see it from my C# project.

I am not familiar with C#, so I am not sure how to do the equivalent of an 'Imports' statement to get visibility of my VB project and its global variable.  Can I do this? Or am I not really thinking this through correctly? (I am a VB guy, so C# is a bit of a mystery still). Thanks.

Comment: Did you forget to add a project reference on the C# project?

Answer (score 4):

Neither VB nor C# supports global variables.

You need to add a reference to the VB project from the C# project so that it can use its members.
You can then access the static field / property of the class / module that you declared it in:

```
ClassName.PropertyName
```

Answer (score 1):

While VB supports module-level declares, C# does not.  In C#, a VB module would appear as a static class.  In VB you can also import entire classes and use their shared/static members globally.  This is also not something that can be achieved in C#.

If, in VB, you have:

```
Public Module MyDeclares

    Public MyGlobalString As String

End Module
```

Then in C#, you would add a reference to that project, and then code like this:

```
using MyProject;
```

and access the field:

```
MyDeclares.MyGlobalString = "Some text";
```

**EDITED**
If you want to access properties and methods in another assembly that are declared internal (friend in VB) then you would modify your AssemblyInfo.vb (or AssemblyInfo.cs) file and add an [**InternalsVisibleTo**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) declaration to the assembly that you want to expose, referencing the assembly (not the namespace) that you want to allow access for.

If your assembly uses strong key signing you will have to include the public key in the definition.  Follow the link for more information including examples.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up staying in the VB project with my module- That was the only way I could get decent visibility among the various parts.

Comment: Have you ever used the InternalsVisibleTo Attribute in the AssembyInfo.vb file?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I haven't, but thanks for the link. I will look at that.

Comment: I'll edit my answer above to include this info bite.